# auto type deduction when ParamType is neither a Pointer nor a Reference

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, auto, type-deduction

I referred to Scott Meyers "More Effective C++" for auto type deduction. It is mentioned that is works the same way as Template type deduction, and there are 3 cases mentioned. My question falls into case 3 (when ParamType is not a pointer or reference), but the outcome is not matching what is described.

```
#include <iostream>

int main (void)
{
   auto i = 2;
   const auto c = &i;

   *c = 4;

   std::cout << "i is " << i;
}
```

It should work as

```
template<typename T>
void f(const T param);

f(&i);   // int *
```

So, `T` here should match to `int *` and the complete type of `param` should be `const int *`.

But, as the program above shows, `c` is not `const int *` but is `int *`.

Can someone explain what am I missing here?

Comment: If `T` is `int *`, then `const T` is `int *const`, not `const int *`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have

```
template<typename T>
void f(const T param);
```

and `T` is a pointer type you don't have `const type *` but instead `type * const` since you are making what `T` is `const`, not what it points to.

That means

```
const auto c = &i;
```

is a `int * const`, a constant pointer to a non constant integer.